# Object reference not set to an instance of object when I return a Type

Tags: c#, return, unity-game-engine, instance

I am getting an annoying `Object reference not set to an instance of object` when I try to return the Grid type from another Unity script.  They method works when I load player data so I dont' know why its not work here.

```
GameLevel gameLevel;
GameLevel.Grid grid;

void Start()
{   
    gameLevel = gameObject.GetComponent<GameLevel>();
    grid = gameLevel.getGrid();
}




using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class GameLevel : MonoBehaviour {
    Grid grid;

    public class Grid{
        public bool[,] playable = new bool[10, 10]{
            {true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true},
            {true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true},
            {true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true},
            {true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true},
            {true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true},
            {true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true},
            {true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true},
            {true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true},
            {true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true},
            {true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true,true}
        };

        public int[,] filled = new int[10, 10]{
            {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,},
            {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,},
            {-1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1,},
            {-1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1,},
            {-1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1,},
            {-1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1,},
            {-1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1,},
            {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,},
            {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,},
            {-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1,},
        };
    }

    void Awake () {
        grid = new Grid();
    }

    public Grid getGrid(){
        return grid;
    }
}
```

Comment: Which line you get this exception?

Comment: are you sure that Awake(..) is called in second case ?

Comment: grid = gameLevel.getGrid();

Comment: yes awake is being called. the problem is because the script is in a child object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved with `GetComponentInChildren()`